# How many distinct lines are there for a rectangular grid of $m \times n$ dots?

Tags: combinatorics

Given points $(x,y)$ on a domain of $0\le x < m$ and  $0\le y < n$ where all are integer.
How many distinct lines (passing through at least two points on the given dots) are  there?
Counting with program must be possible and not difficult enough, but how to do this by hand?

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Count verticals, horizontals and those parallels to the diagonals

Comment: Do you mean the number of lines that go through at least two of the points in that domain?

Comment: How exactly do you define a line ? Can a line have only one point from the grid on it ? Can a line have more than two points from the grid on it ? Does a line have a specific length ?

Comment: @Arthur: Yes. Edited.

Comment: @gandalf61: No restriction for the length.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392290/total-number-of-lines-in-a-2d-grid does this help?

Comment: See OEIS [A018808](https://oeis.org/A018808)

Comment: @Quantum: Your link is awesome! Mine is a duplicate! Thank you!

Comment: @DanielMathias: Good point. Thank you!